# Java Compiler run() method

Tags: java, api, compiler-construction, compilation, java-compiler-api

I found this code online about the JavaCompiler

```
JavaCompiler compiler = ToolProvider.getSystemJavaCompiler();
int result = compiler.run(null, null, null,
             "src/org/kodejava/example/tools/Hello.java");
```

And it says for the `compiler.run(null, null, null` that these three nulls are the default `System.in`, `System.out` and `System.err` respectively. But what do these values actually do as I cannot find the API for these? Could someone please explain?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The Javadoc is [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/tools/Tool.html#run%28java.io.InputStream,%20java.io.OutputStream,%20java.io.OutputStream,%20java.lang.String...%29).

> int run(InputStream in,
>           OutputStream out,
>           OutputStream err,
>           String... arguments)
>
> Run the tool with the given I/O channels and arguments. By convention a tool returns 0 for success and nonzero for errors. Any
>   diagnostics generated will be written to either out or err in some
>   unspecified format.
>
> ```
> Parameters:
>     in - "standard" input; use System.in if null
>     out - "standard" output; use System.out if null
>     err - "standard" error; use System.err if null
>     arguments - arguments to pass to the tool 
> Returns:
>     0 for success; nonzero otherwise
> ```

As for System.in, System.out, and System.err those are global streams that (by default) connect to STDIN, STDERR, and STDOUT. These three are set up by the operating system when the JVM starts. You can pipe them to files, or they just write to (read from) the console.

In this case, you would use the parameters to inspect the compiler output from your program (rather than just sending it out to the user). This is where the "diagnostics written out in some unspecified format" come in.

Answer (score 1):

You can specify your own streams instead of relying on standard System streams. E.g., if you want to redirect an output to some file, you can create File output stream, and pass to #run call.

Answer (score 1):

JavaCompiler is **javax.tools.JavaCompiler** and it implements **javax.tools.Tool** interface, see javadoc for **javax.tools.Tool#run** method.